# Can I do a Post hoc analysis of predicted vs. ground truth data?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, post-hoc

I developed a fully-connected neural network that predicts values based on regression. Is it possible to do post hoc analysis (e.g. Tukey HSD) on these predicted values to find pairwise differences in means? Is there a test besides Tukey that would be valid on predicted vs. sampled data? The model was trained using actual ground truth.

Comment: What are you trying to test? With Tukey's HSD or t-test, you could hypothetically test whether your model is not systematically over-/under-predicting by testing whether the mean difference between predicted vs observed is different from zero. However: a) the null hypothesis is pretty much certain to be false if you have enough data, b) if you test it on the same data have fitted the model on, you'll end up overfitting, and c) is this really the question you want to ask?

Comment: I'm trying to test whether the means of groups of predicted values are statistically significantly different at the 0.05 level. AFAIK, Tukey assumes that means are based on samples from a population. My data is predicted by a neural network that was trained on ground truth of the kind of data the NN predicts.

Comment: Like is said, in that case you're only testing whether your nnet is systematically under-/over-predicting, i.e. whether the mean values it's predicting are higher or lower than the observed values. That's almost definitely bound to be the case, because as long as you have enough data, you will always find that your model isn't perfect in some systematic way. So testing that isn't interesting.

Comment: A better thing would be to test the model's performance on a hold-out dataset (one that you didn't use to train it), or use cross-validation to see how well it performs on unseen data.

Comment: I have tested the model's performance. My predicted data corresponds to properties of soil in a field. I have other data that says that some areas of the field are different than others, so I want to use Tukey HSD to compare the mean of soil properties in one part of the field the mean of another that I believe to be different agronomically. I just don't know if it's valid to use Tukey on data that's predicted vs. sampled from a population.

Comment: To clarify my concern, I worry that model error might be the cause of statistically significant differences in means vs. actual variation in data.

Comment: You should do the pairwise tests on the original data. With predicted data, you're just testing whether the net is predicting differently for different sites. You don't even need a statistical test for that - you can just try to predict fake data where you only change the site, & see if the outputs are different.

Comment: As for model error, if anything, the model should under-predicting the differences between sites, unless it's severely overrfitting. Every model is a simplified, "smooth" summary of the data, so the differences found in the data should be less pronounced in the model.

Comment: Where we have ground truth, we do do pairwise tests on the original data. The problem we're solving with machine learning though, is to provide farmers with information about their fields even when they haven't soil sampled. Interesting comment about the model producing predictions which would under-predict differences in pairwise tests; that makes me feel a little more confident in the results I get doing pairwise tests on the predicted data.